# New navigation component from arch with nested navigation graph

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-jetpack

I have one case and wish to implement it by arch navigation component. For example I have 2 Nav Graphs (main and nested). Can I call main graph from nested and how?
[image]

Comment: @IanLake Can we also use callbacks for navigation graph? Or finishWithResult analog? New android navigation too powerful for simple screens, but not so useful for nested fragments. Or we should to create activity for nested fragments...

Comment: I have exactly same problem have you found solution ??

Comment: anyone found solution?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The point is to get the right `NavController` to navigate in the right graph.
Let's take this scenario as an example:

```
MainActivity
|- MainNavHost
   |- NavBarFragment
   |  |- NestedNavHost
   |  |  |-NestedContentFragment1
   |  |  |-NestedContentFragment2
   |  |
   |  |- BottomNavigationView
   |
   |- LoginFragment
```

The main graph and the nested graph are in separate xml files: this is required, as far as I understood, because the navigations target different layout areas, so they require two different `NavHost`s. Each `Navhost` will need to reference its graph by id, which requires them to be in different resource files.

The point is that to navigate in a specific graph, we must get a reference to the right graph's owner: to do this, when calling `Navigation.findNavController(view)`, the `view` argument is crucial.

Docs say that

> NavHostFragments register their navigation controller at the root of their view subtree such that any descendant can obtain the controller instance through the Navigation helper class's methods

So for example, if inside `NavBarFragment` we write

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
}
```

here `view` is a **parent** of the `NestedNavHost` (that is the nested `NavHostFragment`), not a descendant, meaning that `findNavController` will search upstream in the tree and will return the `MainNavHost`'s `NavController`.

If instead we write

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val nestedNavHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nestedNavHostFragment) as? NavHostFragment
    navController = nestedNavHostFragment?.navController
}
```

where `nestedNavHostFragment` is the id of the `FragmentContainerView` in the layout, we get a reference to the correct `NestedNavHost`. Note the use of `childFragmentManager`, not `parentFragmentManager`.

In case you're still using the deprecated xml `<fragment>` tag, you can write

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val fragmentContainer = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.nestedNavHostFragment)
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(fragmentContainer)
}
```

where `nestedNavHostFragment` is the id of the `<fragment>` tag. We get a reference to the correct `NestedNavHost` now, because the view we pass to `findNavController` belongs to the `NestedNavHost`'s subtree.

Similarly, if you need to get a reference to the main `NavController` from inside a `NestedContentFragment`, here's what we can do:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // we can get the innermost NavController using this view,
    // because we are inside its subtree:
    nestedNavController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

    // we can find the outer NavController passing the owning Activity
    // and the id of a view associated to that NavController,
    // for example the NavHostFragment id:
    mainNavController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!, R.id.mainNavHostFragment)
}
```

Comment: Finally had this figured out... this is tricky and nowhere else has documentation not even on Google's developer website. The "nested navigation" example Google gave has the nested one in the same xml, and you can't refer to it in the BottomNavFragment. You will have to have two xml graphs. And I found it not very covinent, some of the navigations are originated from inside the nested fragment, but going to "present modally" thus you'll have to "navigate" it from the parent graph.

Comment: What did you mean by `fragment tag in the layout`?

Comment: I meant the `id` of the `<fragment />` in the xml layout. As of today, it's been deprecated in favor of `FragmentContainerView`. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView)

Comment: how do we add toolbar back button to the fragments in the NestedNavHost? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... not sure whether something was changed between this post and the version I'm using (2.2.1). I've done exactly the same, but I still get parent `navController` instead the nested `navController`...

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović did you find a solution? still have the same problem.

Comment: Edited to take into account the new strategy with `FragmentContainerView`.

Comment: Can someone post a full example for this to github and if possible another one with ViewPager2 that has child fragments for every tab/page?

Comment: Well, I confirm the idea of retrieving parent/main navController works for me. But please keep in mind that if you navigate to an outer fragment from NestedContentFragment2 - as described in the diagram above - when you press the back button. The app will take you to the start destination of the nestedHost - NestedContentFragment1 in this case.

Comment: @devrocca thanks for the great writeup, I have however one question, using this solution seems to break backstack logic (the back button brings you to the previous "bottom view" and not the previous fragment from the current navigation controller. Did you have the same problem and were you able to fix it ?

Comment: hi @apouche, I didn't have such a problem, I was using the inner NavHost for "horizontal" navigation, that is, back stack had always 1 fragment only. I think you can use the Activity's OnBackPressedDispatcher to intercept the back press to pop the inner back stack.. I recently made a similar structure with an inner back stack in Compose with Compose Navigation and it was way easier to manage ;)

Answer (score 12):

Actually you could use [Global actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) to navigate from a nested nav graph destination to a main nav graph destination.

**Create a global action from nested nav graph to desired destination in main nav graph** (highlighted in the image below)

**example:**

[image: nav graph]

```
<navigation android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
     ... >
     <fragment android:id="@+id/fragStart" .../>
     <fragment .../>
     <fragment .../>

     <navigation  android:id="@+id/nested_nav_graph">
           ...

     <!-- Global Action -->
     <action
         android:id="@+id/action_global_start"
         app:destination="@id/fragStart" />
     </navigation>

</navigation>
```

To navigate to main graph destination use

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_global_start)
```

Comment: Just came back to this question and I wanted to highlight that this is not a solution to the original problem. The nesting of the graphs is at the view level, not at the navigation level, therefore you need 2 NavHosts to achieve the OP structure. You can't nest the graph one in another, you need 2 separate graphs, each unknown to the other, so you can't link them with global actions.

Answer (score 9):

I created an answer with the info devrocca provided. It's a full answer from scratch, i didn't skip anything if anyone ever needs.

[image: Main Fragment of Navigation]

This is the main fragment for navigation. Camera is direct destination without any nested graph, Dashboard has it's own nested graph but it's added to same backstack camera fragment is added. Home has 3 fragments with it's own nav host

```
MainActivity
|- MainNavHost
   |- HomeNavHostFragment
   |  |- NestedNavHost
   |     |-HomeFragment1
   |     |-HomeFragment2
   |     |-HomeFragment3
   |  
   |- nav_graph_dashboard 
   |
   |- CameraFragment
```

Here is the navigation files

Main Navigation `nav_graph.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/main_dest">

    <!-- MainFragment-->
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main_dest"
            android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_3navigation_nestednavhost.blankfragment.MainFragment"
            android:label="MainFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">

        <!-- Camera -->
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_main_dest_to_cameraFragment"
                app:destination="@id/cameraFragment" />

        <!-- Home NavGraph -->
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_main_dest_to_nav_graph_home"
                app:destination="@id/nav_graph_home" />

        <!-- Dashboard  NavGraph-->
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_main_dest_to_nav_graph_dashboard"
                app:destination="@id/nav_graph_dashboard" />

    </fragment>

    <!-- Camera -->
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/cameraFragment"
            android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_3navigation_nestednavhost.blankfragment.CameraFragment"
            android:label="CameraFragment" />


    <!-- Home-->
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_home" />

    <!-- Dashboard-->
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_dashboard" />


    <!-- Global Action Start -->
    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_global_start"
            app:destination="@id/main_dest"
            app:popUpTo="@id/main_dest"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />


</navigation>
```

Dashboard nested navigation graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_dashboard"
        app:startDestination="@id/dashboard_dest">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_dest"
            android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_3navigation_nestednavhost.blankfragment.DashboardFragment1"
            android:label="DashboardFragment1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard1">
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_dashboardFragment1_to_dashboardFragment2"
                app:destination="@id/dashboardFragment2" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment2"
            android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_3navigation_nestednavhost.blankfragment.DashboardFragment2"
            android:label="DashboardFragment2"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard2">
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

And nested navigation graph with it's own NavHost nav_graph_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_home"
        app:startDestination="@id/home_dest">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/home_dest"
            android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_3navigation_nestednavhost.blankfragment.HomeNavHostFragment"
            android:label="HomeHost"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_navhost" />

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/homeFragment1"
            android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_3navigation_nestednavhost.blankfragment.HomeFragment1"
            android:label="HomeFragment1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home1">
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment1_to_homeFragment2"
                app:destination="@id/homeFragment2" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/homeFragment2"
            android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_3navigation_nestednavhost.blankfragment.HomeFragment2"
            android:label="HomeFragment2"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home2">
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment2_to_homeFragment3"
                app:destination="@id/homeFragment3" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/homeFragment3"
            android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial1_3navigation_nestednavhost.blankfragment.HomeFragment3"
            android:label="HomeFragment3"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home3" />

</navigation>
```

Layouts, i only add necessary ones, others are simple layouts with buttons, i add link for sample project with other navigation components samples included.

```
MainActivity


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                    android:id="@+id/main_nav_host_fragment"
                    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

                    app:defaultNavHost="true"
                    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

Main Fragment, this is first fragment that shown in the image used as start of main navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDestCam"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Destination Camera"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnNavGraphHome"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNavGraphHome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nested NavHost Graph Home"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnNavGraphDashboard"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnDestCam" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNavGraphDashboard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nested Graph Dashboard"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNavGraphHome" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</layout>
```

Layout that contains inner `NavHostFragment` for home navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/nested_nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

                app:defaultNavHost="false"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_home" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

MainActivity is for checking main navigation back stack, important thing here is

supportFragmentManager back stack is not updated as you navigate it's childFragmentManager even for main navigation, even if you only have one

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Get NavHostFragment
        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)

        // ChildFragmentManager of NavHostFragment
        val navHostChildFragmentManager = navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager

        navHostChildFragmentManager?.addOnBackStackChangedListener {

            val backStackEntryCount = navHostChildFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
            val fragments = navHostChildFragmentManager.fragments
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment that contains Home navigation's host

```
class HomeNavHostFragment : BaseDataBindingFragment<FragmentHomeNavhostBinding>() {
    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int = R.layout.fragment_home_navhost

    private var navController: NavController? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val nestedNavHostFragment =
            childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nested_nav_host_fragment) as? NavHostFragment
        navController = nestedNavHostFragment?.navController

        navController?.navigate(R.id.homeFragment1)

        listenBackStack()
    }

    private fun listenBackStack() {

        // Get NavHostFragment
        val navHostFragment =
            childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nested_nav_host_fragment)

        // ChildFragmentManager of the current NavHostFragment
        val navHostChildFragmentManager = navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager

        navHostChildFragmentManager?.addOnBackStackChangedListener {

            val backStackEntryCount = navHostChildFragmentManager!!.backStackEntryCount
            val fragments = navHostChildFragmentManager!!.fragments

            Toast.makeText(
                requireContext(),
                "HomeNavHost backStackEntryCount: $backStackEntryCount, fragments: $fragments",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }


        val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {

                val backStackEntryCount = navHostChildFragmentManager!!.backStackEntryCount

                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "HomeNavHost backStackEntryCount: $backStackEntryCount",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()


        if (backStackEntryCount == 1) {
                OnBackPressedCallback@ this.isEnabled = false
                requireActivity().onBackPressed()
            } else {
                navController?.navigateUp()
            }
        }
        }

        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, callback)

    }
}
```

There is one thing i don't know if it's improved in graph or code with nested NavHostFragment

If you set start destination of nav_graph_home `HomeFragment1` instead of `HomeNavHostFragment` it works as dashboard which ignores nested NavHost and added to main back stack of fragments.

Since you are in inner NavHostFragment findNavController() in any home fragment returns the inner one

```
class HomeFragment3 : BaseDataBindingFragment<FragmentHome3Binding>() {
    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int = R.layout.fragment_home3

    private var count = 0

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        dataBinding.btnIncrease.setOnClickListener {
            dataBinding.tvTitle.text = "Count: ${count++}"
        }


        val mainNavController =
            Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)

        dataBinding.btnGoToStart.setOnClickListener {

            // Using destination belong to main_nav_host with nested navHost causes app to crash
//            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_global_start)

            mainNavController.navigate(R.id.action_global_start)/**/
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use global action but it's not required since back navigation in inner navHost directly moves you back to main navigation if you don't use `OnBackPressed`.

Link for [full example](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/NavigationComponents-Tutorials/tree/master/Tutorial1-3Navigation-NestedNavHost) and the other nav component samples if you are interested.

Comment: do you have any idea about this i have made a demo but bckpress proble help me pls if any idea  https://github.com/sunil-singh-chaudhary/Jet-Navigation-Fragments

Comment: How do I build the example from the repo you linked? Only the "External-Tutorial-Navigation-Codelab" module can be built as an app when I cloned the repo.

Comment: @akubi which Android Studio version do you use? I downloaded repo as zip, i'm using Android Studio 4.2 Canary 14, asked me to update gradle with _This project using version 4.1.0beta04 gradle plugin_, i selected begin update and it worked fine for me. I can see every module and tried running few, and they worked fine

Answer (score 3):

Actually is working,
using

```
val host: NavHostFragment? = (childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_app_fragment_container)  as NavHostFragment?)
```

I can navigate from main fragment

Comment: Ok, you can navigate child nav graph from main, but I need to navigate main graph from child. The big problem with navigation graph that I can not get callbacks from children

Comment: You can navigate main graph from child by `Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity,R.id.parent_nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action)` . Also you can use LiveData to communicate to parent from child by a shared ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution to the problem of inner NavController being covered.
You can use custom NavHostFragment which provides you with desired navController.
My code:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        ...
        android:name="MyNavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="false"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/inner_nav">
        ...
    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
```

...

```
class MyNavHostFragment: NavHostFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        MainFragment.innerNavController = navController
    }
}
```

...

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object{
        lateinit var innerNavController: NavController
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val bottomNavigationView = 
             view!!.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(innerNavController)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve it by finding the root navhost controller and then navigating through root nav host controller

```
val Fragment.findRootNavHost: NavController?
get() = this.activity?.let { 
    Navigation.findNavController(it, your_root_fragment_id) 
}

findRootNavHost?.navigate(`your_destination_fragment_id`)
```

Kindly check the [medium](https://lazycoder21.medium.com/android-jetpack-navigation-in-multi-modular-apps-50b240a00dff) article link
[Github](https://github.com/lazycoder-21) repo for the same