# Android navigation component child navigation

Tags: android, navigation

I'm using the Navigation Component on a new Android app but I don't know how to do something

First of all, I have my MainActivity where I have the main_navigation_graph

Main activity NavHostFragment

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation_host_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation_graph"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

Inside of main_navigation_graph there are 3 fragments

Everything works fine here. The problem is when I reach the last fragment, because on this fragment I want to show some child fragments (inside a new NavHostFragment) based on the BottomNavigationView inputs (for the moment)

LastFragment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/dash_board_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/dash_board_bottom_navigation"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/dash_board_navigation_graph" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/dash_board_bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu_navigation"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:background="@color/main_menu_background"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/main_menu_item_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/main_menu_item_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

dash_board_navigation_graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dash_board_navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/destination_home_fragment">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/dash_board_action1"
        app:destination="@id/destination_fragment1"/>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/dash_board_action2"
        app:destination="@id/destination_fragment2"/>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/dash_board_action3"
        app:destination="@id/destination_fragment3"/>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/dash_board_action4"
        app:destination="@id/destination_fragment4"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_fragment1"
        android:name="com.....Fragment1">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_fragment2"
        android:name="com.....Fragment2">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_fragment3"
        android:name="com.....Fragment3">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_fragment4"
        android:name="com.....Fragment4">
    </fragment>
```

When I trigger these actions from the last fragment with:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.dash_board_action1/2/3)
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.asperitass.mobile:id/dash_board_home_action is unknown to this NavController
```

My question is: Is my approach right ? or is this (having multiple levels of navigation) even possible ? Or should I handle this child navigation by using the `childFragmentManager` and inflate a FrameLayout inside my fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you are nesting two NavHostFragments because you wish to only have bottomNav after a flow such as login in the lastFragment,

The problem as I understand is in `findNavController().navigate(R.id.dash_board_action1/2/3)`. Since you have two NavHostFragments you will also have two corresponding NavControllers.

The default `Navigation.findNavController()` will get you the top NavController, but to navigate in child navGraph you need the child NavController which you can get by

```
val fragmentContainer = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.dash_board_navigation)
navController         = Navigation.findNavController(fragmentContainer)
```

For further detail please look at this really good Stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51500083/6269691