# Navigate with BottomNavigationView inside fragment (not activity) using navigation component and navigation graph

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a single `Activity` application. I created a single `Navigation graph` containing all the possible destinations (`Fragment`).

The `Activity` `layout` only contains a `<fragment/>` container as it should be.

There is a main Fragment containing a `BottomNavigationView` where the user can navigate to all the important destinations (3 of them).

When I implement the `BottomNavigationView` as described in many tutorials or event in the official documentation, it replaces the full content of the `Activity`. Therefore, the `BottomNavigationView` is no more displayed as it is contained in a `Fragment` and not in the `Activity`. I want it to inflate the right `layout` in the main Fragment.

Should I use another `Navigation graph`, specific for the main Fragment ?
Should I use a classic `Listener` (But I will loose all the interest of using a `Navigation graph`) ?
Is there a solution I don't know ?

How do I implement it ? I tried to create two different `Navigation graph`, but I can not set it to my `BottomNavigationView`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer:

Create a second `Navigation graph` containing the destination you want your `BottomNavigationView` to access.

In the fragment containing the `BottomNavigationView` make sure to insert a `FragmentContainerView` and an appropriate ID.

Then, thanks to [This answer right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51500083/12016306) you can implement it easily.

Juste refer to the nested NavHost using this:

```
val nestedNavHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_nav_host) as? NavHostFragment

val navController = nestedNavHostFragment?.navController

val bottomNavigationView = view.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)

if (navController != null) {
    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
} else {
    throw RuntimeException("Controller not found")
}
```