# Can we exclude specific fragments from being saved in navigation component stacks?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I've been searching on this topic for a while now, without any success. Since the last update of [Navigation Component 2.5.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.5.0) in combination with `BottomNavigationView` the nav controller retain the stack state for each tab of `BottomNavView`.

Now, I am asking if there is any way to exclude a `graph` or some `fragments` from this rule ?

More in details:

- I have 1 `activity` and the rest are `fragments`
- I have `BottomNavigationView` with 4 tabs
- it is setup with nav controller
- each tab starts a separate `graph` (no confusions) - seems clean, especially in a bigger application
- besides this, I have 2 icons on the toolbar (let's say `help` and `settings`)
- these two icons, are [Global Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) because are started from activity, not from a fragment, and can be accessed from almost any point

Why do I want to exclude some fragments (`help` and `settings`) from this rule to retain their state? Well, because navigating to one of them and then changing the `BottomNavigationView` tabs back and forth, I can end up having these fragments over all of my 4 tabs (or those 4 main graphs)

What I have tried?

1. A tricky solution to add `settings` and `faq` into the `BottomNavigationView` but without being visible, and just link the global action to that tab (manually setting the current item of the `BottomNavView`) - failed, because I've ended up with 6 items in the `BNV` and it will cause a crash, as more than 5 items is a design concern.
2. I tried using two controllers for this activity, 1 to be linked with `BNV` and the other to take care of the global actions, of course I ended up with a bit of a mess.

Maybe I am asking too much from `Android`, but I would like to be able to keep this default behaviour added in `2.5.0` for `Navigation` but at the same time write some exceptions from it. I wouldn't mind manually handling the navigations for each `BNV` tabs, but my issue is with the `global actions`.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I am asking if there is any way to exclude a graph or some fragments from this rule ?

You *can* exclude the entirety of the `NavigationBarView` from the state preservation by using an [overload of `setupWithNavController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupWithNavController(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView,androidx.navigation.NavController,kotlin.Boolean)) with `saveState` set to false. However, you *cannot* exclude certain fragments/routes as you like. It's either all or none, as far as `NavigationUI` is concerned.

As I see it, you have three viable options:

- Locally modify the [`NavigationUI` source](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:navigation/navigation-ui/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.kt) to implement exclusions
- Using nested `NavHostFragment`s, as in your 2nd attempt
- Prevent the user from navigating to another tab while `help` or `settings` fragments are active (hide the BNV with `NavController#addOnDestinationChangedListener`?)

I'd say the second option is by far the ideal one here, as it is also what actually makes sense hierarchically from the way you've defined your app behavior: The global actions need not be coupled to your BNV tabs.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51500083/14354973) nicely demonstrates how you would obtain the `NavController` references. It is actually not too bad to work with once you've gotten a grasp of what `NavController` needs to be doing what. In fact, it's arguably the least hacky design you could go for.